# How to avoid duplication function properties in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a extjs code class User and I would like to extract the common function convertFuntion outside. How could I achieve this?

```
Ext.define('App.model.user.User', {
    extend: 'App.model.BaseModel',
    requires: [
               'Ext.data.writer.Json'
              ],
    fields: [

         { name: "roleIds",
           mapping: "rids",
           convert: convertFunction() {
            //same function body
           }
         },

         {
           name: "fieldIds",
           mapping: "fldids",
           convert: convertFunction() {
             //same function body
           }
         }
    ]
});
```

Is it a good idea to create a static method in some other class and refer it here?

```
Ext.define('App.model.user.User', {
        extend: 'App.model.BaseModel',
        requires: [
                   'Ext.data.writer.Json'
                  ],
        fields: [

             { name: "roleIds",
               mapping: "rids",
               convert: SomeOther.Class.convertFunction
             },

             {
               name: "fieldIds",
               mapping: "fldids",
               convert: SomeOther.Class.convertFunction
             }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Declare a custom field type and use that.

Comment: i see that we could create a custom field type in extjs 5.0, is this possible in extjs 4.2?

Answer (score -1):

Define your convertFunction directly in the model ...

```
    convertFn: function(v, record) {
    console.log(v);
},
```

..and enter through it constructs for each field

```
    constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent();
    var me = this;
    Ext.Array.each(me.fields, function(field, index, selfFields) {
        field.convert = me.convertFn;
    });
}
```

See the full example in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/k5p)